# Ubuntu XFCE no keyboard on wake from suspend

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, suspend, xfce

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with xfce4 replacing Unity. Whenever I suspend my laptop (Sony Vaio vgn-nr260e, 2gb ram, 200gb hdd, previously ran Vista) and wake it, the keyboard will work fine for typing in my password, but will be unusable for a few seconds after. I have to click on the Whisker Menu, close it, then hit the Super key which I have mapped to the Menu before the keyboard will work again.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. This isn't *that* much of a problem, just an annoying thing I want to get rid of.